# Excel VBA change cell value depend to date next to

Tags: excel, vba, date

I would like to setup cell value to specific text if current date is greater than a date next to a cell which I want to set (using VBA only. For example todays date is greater than date in cell M15, so I would like to write "PASSED" to cell L15). And I need set it for whole column.
I have to use VBA because users could delete any formulas in cells.

I have no experience with VBA, I always try to find some code examples which I can edit for my purposes, but in this case I haven't found any.

Comment: *"I have to use VBA because users could delete any formulas in cells."* - or you could just lock the cells that you don't want users to be able to change :)

Comment: Hi dwirony, unfortunately I cannot, because I didn't mention that there's second reason: in some cases users will write a data manually, so I cannot lock whole column.

Comment: I didn't say lock a whole column, I said *cells*. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Amateur Eventing

The title says it all. I'm not entirely satisfied with the result, but it should be something like this, but first...

### Issues

It is not clear what to do if the date isn't greater than today, so you might want to edit the lines where I have chosen `""` to be returned in those cases.

The 'major player' is the `DateCalc` Sub which is running each time the sheet is being recalculated which would be enough if column `M` was containing formulas i.e. when you change data by 'manually' adding values into the cells of column `M`, the **Calculate** event isn't triggered so I had to add the **Change** event which will then change the value in column `L` accordingly. But the `Calculate` event triggers the `Change` event multiple times so it is suppressed more or less successfully using the `Calculation` property.

### The Code

**ThisWorkbook**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Sheet1.DateCalc
End Sub
```

**Sheet1**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  DateCalc
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  DateCalc
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Const cSource As Variant = "M"       ' Column Letter/Number
  Const cTarget As Variant = "L"       ' Column Letter/Number
  Const cString As String = "PASSED"   ' Write String
  Const cFirst As Long = 2             ' First Data Row

  If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual Then Exit Sub

  If Val(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
    If Selection.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
   Else
    If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  End If

  If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(cFirst, cSource) _
      .Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, cSource).End(xlUp).Row)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target > Date Then
      Target.Offset(0, -1) = cString
     Else
      Target.Offset(0, -1) = ""
    End If
  End If

End Sub

Sub DateCalc()

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  Const cSource As Variant = "M"       ' Column Letter/Number
  Const cTarget As Variant = "L"       ' Column Letter/Number
  Const cString As String = "PASSED"   ' Write String
  Const cFirst As Long = 2             ' First Data Row

  Dim i As Long

  For i = cFirst To Cells(Rows.Count, cSource).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, cSource) > Date Then
      Cells(i, cSource).Offset(0, -1) = cString
     Else
      Cells(i, cSource).Offset(0, -1) = ""
    End If
  Next

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008, that is exactly what I need! Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice answer! Although it looks like you forgot to use `cString` :)

Comment: @dwirony: Thanks very much. Corrected.